# Sending multiple variables from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, variables, post, send

I'm trying to pass two javascript variables to PHP. When there's only one then it's working but I have no clue how to send two at once. Here's my code

```
    function save(nr) {
     var xr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var url = 'saveColor.php';
     var text = document.getElementById('color'+nr).value;
     var vars1 = "newText="+text;
     var vars2 = "variable="+nr;

     xr.open("POST", url, true);
     xr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xr.send(vars1);
}
```

So sending the "vars1" variable works fine, but where or how I should put "vars2" to send them at once? Something like

```
xr.send(vars1, vars2);
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('var1', 'var1value');
data.append('var2', 'var2value');
```

and then use it like you tried before

```
xr.send(data);
```

Comment: If I use this will I be able to get those separately or will it be treated as one variable in PHP?

Comment: It will be converted to string like that `var1=var1valuee&var2=var2value`. First check, then post a comment

Comment: I checked it and something is still not working. If I followed your example should I get those variables in PHP via $someVar = $_POST[var1]; etc? Because that's not working ($someVar doesn't show anything when I echo it)

Comment: dump entire `$_POST` variable

Comment: echoing $someVar = var_dump($_POST[var1]); doesn't output anything either if that's what you meant.

Comment: I checked something and "data" outputs "[object FormData]" instead of string you mentioned.
EDIT: Instead of trying to append I just did that
var data = 'vars1='+text+'&vars2='+nr;
It's working now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be implemented this way

```
var strURL = "auto_ppm_plan_generation_table.php?ppm_frequency=" + ppm_frequency + "&ppm_month=" + ppm_month + "&ppm_week=" + ppm_week;
```